# Looking for ideas to quickly flow content

Tags: javascript

I'm writing some code that wraps various content into columns of text (and images, videos, etc).  The code works fine, but due to the algorithm I'm using it's rather slow, specifically this general logic:

- add something (text for this example) to a column
- check to see if column.scrollHeight > column.offsetHeight (this requires a DOM reflow)

  - if yes, start to binary split the text until it's shorter

Basically my issue is that I'm adding an unknown amount of text to a column, so after each chunk of text I check the column's scroll height which requires the browser to actively reflow the DOM in order to give me the correct scrollHeight.  So I have 50-100 or more reflows in order to properly lay everything out.

Any general ideas on how to avoid most of these?

Comment: This seems to me to be the slow part: `binary split the text until it's shorter`. Why not just figure out what it should be split to in one run?

Comment: what are your requirements for supporting different browsers? depending on the browser you can set up columns in native CSS

Comment: @TravisJ -- because I don't know where it should be split.  I suppose I could use a textrange to figure it out... In any case, that's actually not most of the issue since that is only 3 or 4 checks for each column as opposed to the other 20 or so.

Comment: @BrianGlaz -- The layouts are too complicated for CSS3 columns :)

Comment: @cwolves - What about checking the page size, and then dynamically setting a range for the columns. This would require text placed in the columns to fit.

Comment: @TravisJ -- I don't quite follow that?

Comment: @cwolves - I don't really know what you are truly doing here so this is an assumption. But, based on the use of the keyword columns I am assuming you will have multiple columns and that you don't want them to be too wide?

Comment: @TravisJ -- I have multiple columns (not necessarily next to each other) and I want content to flow from one to the next.  So when content reaches the end of the first column it should continue in the next.  That's what the checks are for, to figure out when it has hit the end of a column

Comment: We're talking about binary splitting text only - doesn't the other elements you've mentioned (images, videos) need to be "moved" to the other column if they happen to be in area that exceeds first column height?

Comment: @WTK - yes, anything other than text just gets moved to the next column

Comment: I'm still thinking about how to solve this, so to narrow it down: does the content of the said column may be floated, by that I mean if text may flow around other elements (images, videos)? Or it's the more simple case where the text/image or video always occupies full width of the column? And second question - what browsers do you want to target, does solution may rely on css3 and/or other modern browser features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render the content multiple times. Since the first time would cache it, this should be fairly fast. The reason for the multiple rendering would be as follows.

1. Render the original content in a hidden area
2. Check to see what the column width is compared to content
3. Overlay the content over the column, but beneath the page. This
      will cut off part of the content that is overflowing. You can accomplish with
      z-indexing or with `overflow: hidden;`
4. Based on what the check from step 2 was, overlay a copy of the content with
      the calculated offset in the next column in the same fashion, hiding the
      extra content.
5. Keep track of the rendered content versus total content so you can tell how many
      columns you need to do this to if there are multiple columns.

Comment: That approach would probably result with some content being cut off by half, since you're not checking if there's any content at the edge of the overflown column.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the same thing Travis J is suggesting, but I'm not sure, I don't quite understand his solution.

You could render everything first, on a single column, then loop through the elements top-down to know when to split, based on your desired column height versus each element's `offsetTop` plus `height`. When you find an element to break at, cache its position and go on. At the end you should have an array with the list of elements to break at, so you can actually split the content in columns.

Does this make any sense to you?